# Comparing 2 pdf's - Error

Tags: pdf, delegates, compare, decode

I've to compare two pdf's visually and get the output pdf. For this, I tried the steps mentioned in some other link which mentioned below.

[Comparison of two pdf files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6704594/comparison-of-two-pdf-files/13758709#13758709)

I installed ImageMagick, pdftk, Ghostscript. while trying to compare, using the above mentioned cmd,

compare \
   -verbose \
   -debug coder -log "%u %m:%l %e" \
    somewhere/firstpdf_page_001.pdf \
    somewhere/2ndpdf_page_001.pdf \
   -compose src \
    somewhereelse/diff_page_001.pdf
I'm getting the error.

C:\pdftk\ImageMagick-6.7.3-Q16>compare -verbose -debug coder -log "%u %m:%l %e" "C:\Users\velprakashk\Desktop\Velu\test.pdf" "C:\Users\velprakashk\Desktop\Velu\ test2.pdf" -composite src "C:\Users\velprakashk\Desktop\Velu\rrr.pdf" Magick: no decode delegate for this image format C:\Users\velprakashk\Desktop\V elu\test.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532. Magick: no decode delegate for this image formatC:\Users\velprakashk\Desktop\V elu\test2.pdf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532.

Can anyone guide me... My 2 pdf's to be compared are having 1 page only...

Comment: ImageMagick seems unable to decode some image in your PDF. Would you share your sample PDFs for inspection and further analysis?

Comment: Try [DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html), it works fine.